# Android string file to image

Tags: java, android

from server side an image is being sent to me.
The image i receive it as string, what server side is sending me is the entire file.
How can I read it in android side?

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", null); 
// tempFile.wr
byte[] bytes = output.toString().getBytes();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(bytes);
```

output is the result i receive, its string which is the entire file send from server side.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
m2.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

I am getting SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

this code running produces this log cat

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", null);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(output.toString().getBytes());
fos.close();  
System.out.println(""+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
myOptions.inDither = true;
myOptions.inScaled = false;
myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
m2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

http://www.speedyshare.com/8BdVs/log.txt

Comment: It is in base64 or somethig else?

Comment: yes , its a file actually. the output i get is a file.

Comment: if i do this  byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(output.toString(),Base64.DEFAULT); i get bad base 64 as error

Comment: use this base64 class in your code and follow the decoder and encoder methods..it will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/22601645/964741

Comment: how do you download the file? which library do you use? could you show more code?

Comment: no the file is sent in output. I call a url, and that url rather then returning to me json returns to me a long value which is the file..

Comment: to further add, there is no url link to download the image file from. the entire file is sent to me.

Comment: do not convert `output` to string, use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` method

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to convert into stream from base64 decoded string of image. This will only work if it has properly encoded in Base64 and stored it in your server

```
 Bitmap img = null;
 InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
 img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

Comment: can you paste the whole stacktrace to me? or it would be better to give me the string

Comment: can you please check this with you string and let me know you is the output..

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/